# Error when add record to sqlite database

Tags: android

I am creating a app for my cell and receive these error when save the data. I remove the imports to have a better visualisation.

```
03-19 22:16:16.040  21727-21727/com.thedarkstudios.spock.venlacesrf E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.thedarkstudios.spock.venlacesrf.dao.TorreDAO.createTorre(TorreDAO.java:47)
        at com.thedarkstudios.spock.venlacesrf.activities.CadastrarTorre$2.onClick(CadastrarTorre.java:82)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5076)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My dbHelper (seems ok):

```
/**
 * Created by Usuario on 19/03/2015.
 */

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "venlacesrf.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_TORRES = "torres";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String COL_LNG = "lng";
    public static final String COL_LOCAL = "local";
    public static final String COL_DESC = "desc";
    public static final String COL_ALTURA = "altura";


    private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TORRES + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL_LAT + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
            + COL_LNG + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
            + COL_LOCAL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COL_ALTURA + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
            + ");";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DataBaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Atualizando banco de dados de " + oldVersion + " para "
                        + newVersion + ", que irá destruir todos os seus dados.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TORRES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
/**
 * Created by Spock on 18/03/2015.
 */
public class Torre {

    private int id;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private String local;
    private String desc;
    private double altura;

    public Torre(){

    }

    public Torre(int id, double lat, double lng, String local, String desc, double altura){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.local = local;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local = local;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }

    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }
}
```

DAO (Data Acess Object):

```
public class TorreDAO {


    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { DataBaseHelper.COL_ID,
            DataBaseHelper.COL_LAT, DataBaseHelper.COL_LNG,
            DataBaseHelper.COL_LOCAL, DataBaseHelper.COL_DESC,
            DataBaseHelper.COL_ALTURA};

    public TorreDAO(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Torre createTorre(double lat, double lng, String local, String desc, double altura) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.COL_LAT, lat);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.COL_LNG, lng);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.COL_LOCAL, local);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.COL_DESC, desc);
        values.put(DataBaseHelper.COL_ALTURA, altura);
        long insertId = database.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_TORRES, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_TORRES,
                allColumns, DataBaseHelper.COL_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Torre newTorre = cursorToTorre(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newTorre;
    }

    public void deleteTorre(Torre torre) {
        long id = torre.getId();
        System.out.println("Torre deletada com id: " + id);
        database.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_TORRES, DataBaseHelper.COL_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List<Torre> getAllTorres() {
        List<Torre> torres = new ArrayList<Torre>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_TORRES,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Torre torre = cursorToTorre(cursor);
            torres.add(torre);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return torres;
    }

    private Torre cursorToTorre(Cursor cursor) {
        Torre torre = new Torre();
        torre.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        torre.setLat(cursor.getDouble(1));
        torre.setLng(cursor.getDouble(2));
        torre.setLocal(cursor.getString(3));
        torre.setDesc(cursor.getString(4));
        torre.setAltura(cursor.getDouble(5));
        return torre;
    }
}
```

Activity (Form):

```
public class CadastrarTorre extends ActionBarActivity {


    private EditText txtLat;
    private EditText txtLong;
    private EditText txtLocal;
    private EditText txtDescricao;
    private EditText txtAltura;
    private Button btnObtLocal;
    private Button btnSalvar;

    TorreDAO torreDAO = new TorreDAO(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar_torre);

        setupElements();
    }

    // Cria os elementos;
    public void setupElements(){
        txtLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLat);
        txtLong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLong);
        txtLocal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLocal);
        txtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        txtAltura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAltura);

        btnObtLocal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObtLocal);
        btnSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);

        // Inicia a captura do gps ao clicar no botao;
        btnObtLocal.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                iniciaGPS();
            }
        });

        btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Torre objTorre = new Torre();

                objTorre.setLat(Double.parseDouble(txtLat.getText().toString()));
                objTorre.setLng(Double.parseDouble(txtLong.getText().toString()));
                objTorre.setLocal(txtLocal.getText().toString());
                objTorre.setDesc(txtDescricao.getText().toString());
                objTorre.setAltura(Double.parseDouble(txtAltura.getText().toString()));

                // Transforma para String
                //String torre =  String.valueOf(objTorre.getLatitude());

                // Coloca na tela;
                //txtLocal.setText(torre.toString());
                System.out.println("Latitude: " + objTorre.getLat());
                System.out.println("Longitude: " + objTorre.getLng());
                System.out.println("Local: " + objTorre.getLocal());
                System.out.println("Descrição: " + objTorre.getDesc());
                System.out.println("Altura (mts): " + objTorre.getAltura());

                torreDAO.createTorre(objTorre.getLat(), objTorre.getLng(), objTorre.getLocal(),
                        objTorre.getDesc(), objTorre.getAltura());
            }
        });

    }

    public void iniciaGPS(){
```

....
        }

```
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. What's the problem with it? Create a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem, if you want people to be able to help.

Comment: post your logcat where it shown `caused by....`

Answer (score 0):

You posted a lot of code , but it seems like you're only missing to "open" your connection before saving data:

```
   torreDAO.open(); 
   torreDAO.createTorre(objTorre.getLat(), objTorre.getLng(), objTorre.getLocal(),
                    objTorre.getDesc(), objTorre.getAltura());
```